# Objective C - Brute Force Algorithm

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, md5

I am coding an Objective-C MD5 hash "decrypter". Since you cannot decrypt such a hash function, I am approaching it with a brute force algorithm, that tries every single password combination until it found the correct one or not. I would highly appreciate any help from you guys to improve the algorithm to make it even faster. I am currently having approx. **28,000** guesses per second on my iMac and **7,000** on an iPhone 6. I have attached the code.

```
-(void)brute_sequentialWithMaxLength:(int)length
{
iterateFurther = YES;

char * buf = malloc(length + 1);
for (int i=1; i <= length; i++)
{
    memset(buf, 0, length+1);
    [self brute_implWithChar:buf andIndex:0 andDepth:i];
}

free(buf);

if (![pm_crackingStatusLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Found"])
{
    pm_crackingStatusLabel.text = @"Exhausted";
}
}



-(void)brute_implWithChar:(char*)str andIndex:(int)index andDepth:(int)max_depth
{ 

for (int i=0; i < [pm_maskArray count] && iterateFurther == YES;i++)
{

    alph = [[pm_maskArray objectAtIndex:i] characterAtIndex:0];

    str[index] = alph;
    if (index == max_depth - 1)
    {

        if ([[self makeMD5StringFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",str]] isEqualToString:pm_hashString])
        {
            NSLog(@"Found");
            iterateFurther = NO;
        }


    }
    else
    {

        [self brute_implWithChar:str andIndex:index+1 andDepth:max_depth];
    }

}   
}
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: You'll get more help on Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Can a mod please move this question to Stack Exchange Code Review please: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Obvious things would be to stop using Objective C and write your own SIMD optimised C/C++ implementation.  Also multi-threading would give you a good win.

Answer (score 1):

ObjC is the wrong tool for this job. I'm a big fan of ObjC, but tight inner-loops of high-performance code are not what it's about. You should be able to do everything in the above code easily with C data structures and C functions (no ObjC methods). In fact, you have C data structures (a `char*`) and you waste a huge amount of time generating an `NSString` from that (which I'm certain `makeMD5StringFromString` turns back into an `NSData` and then effectively converts back to a `char*`).

You should of course use Apple's MD5 code (`CC_MD5`), but there's no reason to make any other calls outside your code, including calls into Foundation.

Note that this problem is extremely well explored by [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/). I get why someone might want to explore it on their own, and JtR is GPL, so none of its authors' work can be incorporated into non-GPL code, but there is no need for this kind of product except as an interesting problem to learn how to improve performance.

If that is your goal, you should spend a lot of time in Instruments. You should already know exactly where your code is spending its time. Then SO can help you find ways to improve that one piece that's causing your trouble. The first lesson you should take away is this: never, ever, allocate memory if you can possibly help it. (The fact that you should never make a method call is so basic it isn't even a lesson.)

But step one is to rewrite this in C (or even Swift, which at least has a hope of optimizing effectively). ObjC is not the right tool. Dynamic dispatch is the enemy of super-high performance.

BTW, for comparison, JtR can test several million MD5 hashes per second on my MBP. You're currently on the wrong order of magnitude.

Comment: Thanks Rob for your answer. I am absolutely aware of Objective C being the wrong tool for this kind of functions. The reason why I used ObjC is simply that I want to use it on my iPhone as some kind of mobile md5 decryption. I managed to write this code in C only and it worked quite well. Using [cuda-hashcat](http://hashcat.net) on my iMac I'm testing 2.2 billion hashes per second so I do know that 28,000 is quite ridiculous compared to the performance a gpu powered application might has. I'm switching to Swift little by little.

Comment: iPhone runs raw C just fine (C is just a subset of ObjC). But I'd recommend CC_MD5, which is a builtin function on iPhone (and Mac), rather than bringing over your own MD5 implementation.